# Can multiple threads sniff on same interface at same time?

Tags: c++, pcap, tcpdump, libpcap, winpcap

Hi i am writing a program to sniff packets, using pcap of tcpdump.

For each call from user,a thread is created. That thread will sniff on an interface(probably loopback) and write the captured packets to a file. (pcap dumping)

Is it possible, another thread at the same time sniff on the same interface?

Answer (score 0):

No.  Libpcap is *not* thread-safe for access to a single `pcap_t *`.  Newer versions *are* thread safe in that a call that works on one `pcap_t *` can be executed in a separate thread from a call that works on a *different* `pcap_t *` (in earlier versions, `pcap_compile()` wasn't thread safe *at all*, even when run on two different `pcap_t *`'s), but it is *not* safe to have two separate threads working on the *same* `pcap_t *`.

Comment: ok. i was using winapi createthread and so far it worked. Only pcap_breakloop was used in the second thread.

Comment: OK, sorry, `pcap_breakloop()` *is* the one routine that can safely be used on a particular `pcap_t *` in thread other than the one in which that `pcap_t *` is mainly being used.

Answer (score 0):

I have two different programs that sniff on the same interface. One opens the interface and process data and the other opens the same interface for logging. I have checked and I didn't see any packet loss on either of them.
These are not in the same program on two different threads, these are two separate programs. I can assume that if you create two `pcap_t` handles on different threads to sniff the same interface you wont face problems.